# flutter v2.2.1 with firebase realtime database configuration error

Tags: firebase, flutter

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method DatabaseReference#set on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database)

Flutter with firebase error when i post my realtime data,

Comment: update your question with more details of explanation

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.